# Верификация номера телефона через смс код

Tags: php, api, sms

Как сделать проверку номера телефона в форме через смс код? Есть сервис https://smsc.ru/api/code/#menu с примером кода, но не могу понять как его использовать в своей форме. Не получается все это вместе собрать воедино.

Форма простая

```html
   <form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uname" value="" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your name" required="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" value=""  placeholder="Enter valid mobile number" required="">
    <button type="submit" name="sendopt" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Отправить</button>
 </form>
 <form method="POST" action="">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP" maxlength="5" required="">
   <button type="submit" name="verifyotp" class="btn">Верифицировать</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш весь код ? Или это всё что у вас есть?

Comment: Код который сам написал удалил так как посчитал что он не правильный, раз не работает

Comment: Вся суть в том чтоб вы показывали что у вас есть и вам помогут найти ошибку и исправить её. В текущем виде ваш вопрос выглядит как "сделайте за меня" а это как известно для биржи фриланса больше подходит